# HELVETICA cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, fonts, pdfbox

I am following a tutorial online. I am working with PDFBox with Eclipse and am having issues with loading the font that is suppose to be in the libraries. I've loaded all 9 jars into my external libraries and the different fonts give me the same "cannot be resolved or is not a field".

```
import java.io.IOException;  
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.*;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont;

public class PCSRR {
    
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
         PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();   
         PDPage blankPage = new PDPage();  
         doc.addPage( blankPage );  
         
         PDPage page = doc.getPage(1);  
         PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);  
         
         //Begin the Content stream   
         contentStream.beginText();   
         contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.HELVETICA , 14);
         contentStream.newLineAtOffset(20, 450);  
            String text = "Hi!!! This is the first sample PDF document.";  
         contentStream.showText(text);        
         contentStream.endText();  
            System.out.println("New Text Content is added in the PDF Document.");  
         contentStream.close();  
         
         doc.save("C:\\Users\\Aaron\\Desktop\\pdfbox\\practice.pdf");  
            System.out.println("PDF created"); 
         doc.close();  
    }
}
```

[image: External Jars]

Answer (score 7):

Use this line of code instead.

```
 contentStream.setFont(new PDType1Font(Standard14Fonts.FontName.HELVETICA), 14);
```

Answer (score -2):

I removed version 3.0.0-alpha2 and added 2.0.24 and was able to pick the font. 3.0.0-alpha2 was not working for me.

Comment: 3.0.0 has a different API.

Comment: https://pdfbox.apache.org/3.0/migration.html